How to make Rollup.js preserve module exports with multiple entry points
I have a project with two modules chart.js and slider.js, and slider imports a class from chart. Now I want to bundle both with Rollup.js.
My rollup config looks like this
export default {
    input: [
        'src/chart.js',
        'src/slider.js'
    ],
    output: {
        format: 'es',
        dir: 'dist'
    },
};

When I run Rollup, it produces 3 files instead of 2: chart.js, slider.js, and additionally, chart-DqLRgW92.js. The last file actually contains my Chart class exporting it under a different name:
export { Chart as a };

And then chart.js only renames the export back to Chart:
export { a as Chart } from './chart-DqLRgW92.js';

There is nothing else in the chart.js except this single line.
slider.js imports Chart from chart-DqLRgW92.js:
import { C as Chart } from './chart-DqLRgW92.js';

On the other hand, if I run Rollup separately on each entry file, it produces a single output for each entry. Is there a way to setup Rollup to generate two output files and export the Chart class from chart.js without renaming it back and forth?
